# How to parse irregular JSON response from US Census API call?

Tags: json, parsing, jq, census, hjson

The following is the response from a US Census API call. It uses irregular JSON (or simple javascript object) format in the response. In the form of 
{ one set of data} { second set of data}. How can one parse the second set, namely the array data that comes after the data: tag in the second { } block. Thank you very much.

```
{ 'Incorporated Places': 
   [ { OID: 27890266655573,
       STATE: '24',
       FUNCSTAT: 'A',
       NAME: 'Annapolis city',
       AREAWATER: 2344089,
       LSADC: '25',
       CENTLON: '-076.5039149',
       PLACECC: 'C1',
       BASENAME: 'Annapolis',
       INTPTLAT: '+38.9721517',
       MTFCC: 'G4110',
       PLACE: '01600',
       CBSAPCI: 'N',
       GEOID: '2401600',
       PLACENS: '02390562',
       CENTLAT: '+38.9706625',
       INTPTLON: '-076.5053318',
       NECTAPCI: 'N',
       AREALAND: 18668789,
       OBJECTID: 17981 } ],
  Counties: 
   [ { OID: 27590266629759,
       STATE: '24',
       FUNCSTAT: 'A',
       AREAWATER: 448136044,
       NAME: 'Anne Arundel County',
       LSADC: '06',
       CENTLON: '-076.5675544',
       BASENAME: 'Anne Arundel',
       INTPTLAT: '+38.9916103',
       COUNTYCC: 'H1',
       MTFCC: 'G4020',
       COUNTY: '003',
       GEOID: '24003',
       CENTLAT: '+38.9939578',
       INTPTLON: '-076.5607311',
       AREALAND: 1074250699,
       COUNTYNS: '01710958',
       OBJECTID: 1026 } ],
  'Census Tracts': 
   [ { OID: 20790266676100,
       STATE: '24',
       FUNCSTAT: 'S',
       NAME: 'Census Tract 7061.01',
       AREAWATER: 249211,
       LSADC: 'CT',
       CENTLON: '-076.4923901',
       BASENAME: '7061.01',
       INTPTLAT: '+38.9772243',
       MTFCC: 'G5020',
       COUNTY: '003',
       GEOID: '24003706101',
       CENTLAT: '+38.9778105',
       INTPTLON: '-076.4922890',
       AREALAND: 1216538,
       OBJECTID: 9052,
       TRACT: '706101' } ],
  '2010 Census Blocks': 
   [ { BLKGRP: '2',
       OID: 210404225273924,
       FUNCSTAT: 'S',
       STATE: '24',
       AREAWATER: 0,
       NAME: 'Block 2014',
       SUFFIX: '',
       LSADC: 'BK',
       CENTLON: '-076.4906778',
       LWBLKTYP: 'L',
       BASENAME: '2014',
       BLOCK: '2014',
       INTPTLAT: '+38.9788709',
       MTFCC: 'G5040',
       COUNTY: '003',
       GEOID: '240037061012014',
       CENTLAT: '+38.9788709',
       INTPTLON: '-076.4906778',
       AREALAND: 15203,
       OBJECTID: 3877566,
       TRACT: '706101' } ],
  States: 
   [ { OID: 27490140608205,
       STATE: '24',
       FUNCSTAT: 'A',
       NAME: 'Maryland',
       AREAWATER: 6980364276,
       LSADC: '00',
       CENTLON: '-076.6789663',
       STUSAB: 'MD',
       BASENAME: 'Maryland',
       INTPTLAT: '+38.9466584',
       DIVISION: '5',
       MTFCC: 'G4000',
       STATENS: '01714934',
       GEOID: '24',
       CENTLAT: '+38.9463607',
       INTPTLON: '-076.6744939',
       REGION: '3',
       AREALAND: 25150702890,
       OBJECTID: 5 } ] }
{ level: 'state',
  sublevel: true,
  variables: [ 'income', 'population', 'C24010_011E', 'education_masters' ],
  year: 2015,
  api: 'acs5',
  lat: 38.9786,
  lng: -76.4911,
  state: '24',
  county: '003',
  tract: '706101',
  blockGroup: '2',
  place: '01600',
  place_name: 'Annapolis city',
  data: 
   [ { name: 'Allegany County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '001',
       income: '40551',
       population: '73549',
       C24010_011E: '1039',
       education_masters: '3255' },
     { name: 'Anne Arundel County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '003',
       income: '89860',
       population: '555280',
       C24010_011E: '9306',
       education_masters: '45047' },
     { name: 'Baltimore County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '005',
       income: '67095',
       population: '822959',
       C24010_011E: '16725',
       education_masters: '60803' },
     { name: 'Calvert County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '009',
       income: '95828',
       population: '90114',
       C24010_011E: '986',
       education_masters: '5628' },
     { name: 'Caroline County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '011',
       income: '52465',
       population: '32661',
       C24010_011E: '328',
       education_masters: '1011' },
     { name: 'Carroll County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '013',
       income: '85385',
       population: '167444',
       C24010_011E: '2977',
       education_masters: '11030' },
     { name: 'Cecil County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '015',
       income: '66396',
       population: '101960',
       C24010_011E: '1421',
       education_masters: '4239' },
     { name: 'Charles County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '017',
       income: '90607',
       population: '152754',
       C24010_011E: '2367',
       education_masters: '8300' },
     { name: 'Dorchester County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '019',
       income: '47093',
       population: '32534',
       C24010_011E: '461',
       education_masters: '1349' },
     { name: 'Frederick County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '021',
       income: '83700',
       population: '241373',
       C24010_011E: '5026',
       education_masters: '18962' },
     { name: 'Garrett County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '023',
       income: '45432',
       population: '29813',
       C24010_011E: '344',
       education_masters: '1434' },
     { name: 'Harford County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '025',
       income: '80465',
       population: '248966',
       C24010_011E: '4243',
       education_masters: '18132' },
     { name: 'Howard County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '027',
       income: '110238',
       population: '304115',
       C24010_011E: '7687',
       education_masters: '42253' },
     { name: 'Kent County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '029',
       income: '58147',
       population: '19923',
       C24010_011E: '261',
       education_masters: '1189' },
     { name: 'Montgomery County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '031',
       income: '99435',
       population: '1017859',
       C24010_011E: '33271',
       education_masters: '132184' },
     { name: 'Prince George\'s County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '033',
       income: '74260',
       population: '892816',
       C24010_011E: '16164',
       education_masters: '58017' },
     { name: 'Queen Anne\'s County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '035',
       income: '85963',
       population: '48600',
       C24010_011E: '876',
       education_masters: '3419' },
     { name: 'St. Mary\'s County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '037',
       income: '86987',
       population: '109614',
       C24010_011E: '1625',
       education_masters: '7640' },
     { name: 'Somerset County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '039',
       income: '35154',
       population: '25980',
       C24010_011E: '208',
       education_masters: '715' },
     { name: 'Talbot County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '041',
       income: '58228',
       population: '37799',
       C24010_011E: '711',
       education_masters: '2855' },
     { name: 'Washington County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '043',
       income: '56228',
       population: '149270',
       C24010_011E: '1861',
       education_masters: '6313' },
     { name: 'Wicomico County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '045',
       income: '52278',
       population: '101182',
       C24010_011E: '1788',
       education_masters: '5466' },
     { name: 'Worcester County, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '047',
       income: '56773',
       population: '51519',
       C24010_011E: '781',
       education_masters: '3110' },
     { name: 'Baltimore city, Maryland',
       state: '24',
       county: '510',
       income: '42241',
       population: '622454',
       C24010_011E: '15642',
       education_masters: '36590' } ] }
```

Comment: The data is not in the format {  {set # 1} {set # 2} }

Comment: the response data is in the format {set # 1} {set # 2} - how to get just the second set and skip the first one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that tools such as hjson (http://hjson.org/users.html), any-json (https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-json) and
json5 (npm install json5)
can handle both the top-level quasi-JSON objects, e.g.

```
hjson -j census.2.txt
```

or:

```
any-json --input-format=cson census.2.txt
```

or:

```
json5 -c census.2.txt
```

The not-so-good news is that these three tools can only handle one top-level object at a time.

### Option 1: split

So one possibility would be to split the response into two.
This would be easy if it can be assumed that only the top-level objects
have an opening brace (`{`)  in column 1.  Under this assumption, there are dozens of possibilities,
e.g. using `split -p '^{'`

### Option 2: hjson

Another possibility would be to wrap the response in square brackets, and use `hjson` to convert the pseudo-array into valid JSON.

Thus if you only want the second object (converted to valid JSON), you could run:

```
(echo "["; cat census.txt; echo "]") | hjson -j | jq '.[1]'
```

This uses the wondrous [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) utility, but there are others that can do the job as well.